# Code to load JSON file into python which is not line by line with many objects?

Tags: python, json

I was able to load a JSON file into python using this code

```
with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
    json_data = [line for line in json.load(f)]
```

But this will work only if the json file is line by line as follows:

```
[
  {"sepalLength": 5.1, "sepalWidth": 3.5, "petalLength": 1.4, "petalWidth": 0.2, "species": "setosa"},
  {"sepalLength": 4.9, "sepalWidth": 3.0, "petalLength": 1.4, "petalWidth": 0.2, "species": "setosa"},
  {"sepalLength": 4.7, "sepalWidth": 3.2, "petalLength": 1.3, "petalWidth": 0.2, "species": "setosa"},
  {"sepalLength": 4.6, "sepalWidth": 3.1, "petalLength": 1.5, "petalWidth": 0.2, "species": "setosa"}
]
```

What if the json dataset was as follows:

```
[
  {"sepalLength": 5.1,
 "sepalWidth": 3.5,
 "petalLength": 1.4,
 "petalWidth": 0.2,
 "species": "setosa"},

{"sepalLength": 5.1,
 "sepalWidth": 3.5,
 "petalLength": 1.4,
 "petalWidth": 0.2,
 "species": "setosa"}
]
```

How would I be able to load the file into python?

EDIT: This is the error I have been getting when downloading a json dataset online:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    json_data = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 768: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: json_data = json.load(f)

Comment: Have you tried loading ? if yes what is the error you'r getting else try loading it first.

Comment: @sushanth I edited the error in.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "line by line". Probably the JSON file you have is *encoded* using a charset which you're not matching. Use `open(..., encoding='the correct charset here')` to treat it properly. What the correct charset is we can't tell you.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `json.load()` and set the encoding of your opened file.

```
with open(json_file, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
```